# apt-offline only install specific packages

Tags: apt

`apt-offline` seems like a really great option if you have a server that does not have network connectivity and you want to install a few packages on it.

The problem I have is that I only want to install a *few* packages and there seem to only be options for an `upload` or an `upgrade` and to *also* install the *few* packages I want. How do I get `apt-offline` to only create an install database for the packages I want to install?

Answer (score 1):

You can install other packages. If you use apt-offline with the **--install-packages** option like for example:

`sudo apt-offline set package-offline.sig --install-packages package_name`

It will create a signature for the installation of *package_name* and its dependencies.